# C# XmlReader can't read "<" as InnerXmlText

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have written a XML-Parser and in the InnerXml I got text like this:

```
<Name ...><<interface>>Employee</Name>
<!-- "<<interface>>Employee" is the InnerXml Text and I need it as string -->
```

My Code for reading the text looks like this:

```
     string getName(XmlReader reader)
        {
            string className;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.HasValue)
                {
                    className += reader.Value;
                }
            }
            return className;
        }
```

But after my XmlTextReader is reading this Line, I'm getting an exception:

```
Nachricht: 
    System.Xml.XmlException : Ein Name darf nicht mit dem Zeichen '<', hexadezimaler Wert 0x3C, beginnen.
```

which means, that the '<' character is not readable or the Text can not begin with a character of '<'.
Can anyone explain me this pls?
Basically it is converting by itself to this (in the XML-File):

```
<Name...>&lt;&lt;interface&gt;&gt;Employee</Name> <!-- instead of <<interface>> -->
```

the entire .grapml File (it is a different xml notation):
(at y:NodeLabel)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:java="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/1.0/java" xmlns:sys="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/markup/primitives/2.0" xmlns:x="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/markup/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:y="http://www.yworks.com/xml/graphml" xmlns:yed="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yed/3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://www.yworks.com/xml/schema/graphml/1.1/ygraphml.xsd">
  <!--Created by yEd 3.19.1-->
  <key for="port" id="d0" yfiles.type="portgraphics"/>
  <key for="port" id="d1" yfiles.type="portgeometry"/>
  <key for="port" id="d2" yfiles.type="portuserdata"/>
  <key attr.name="url" attr.type="string" for="node" id="d3"/>
  <key attr.name="description" attr.type="string" for="node" id="d4"/>
  <key for="node" id="d5" yfiles.type="nodegraphics"/>
  <key for="graphml" id="d6" yfiles.type="resources"/>
  <key attr.name="url" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d7"/>
  <key attr.name="description" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d8"/>
  <key for="edge" id="d9" yfiles.type="edgegraphics"/>
  <graph edgedefault="directed" id="G">
    <node id="n0">
      <data key="d5">
        <y:UMLClassNode>
          <y:Geometry height="116.0" width="131.0" x="1301.3333333333333" y="41.0"/>
          <y:Fill color="#FFCC00" transparent="false"/>
          <y:BorderStyle color="#000000" type="line" width="1.0"/>
          <y:NodeLabel alignment="center" autoSizePolicy="content" fontFamily="Dialog" fontSize="12" fontStyle="bold" hasBackgroundColor="false" hasLineColor="false" height="33.40234375" horizontalTextPosition="center" iconTextGap="4" modelName="internal" modelPosition="c" textColor="#000000" verticalTextPosition="bottom" visible="true" width="82.052734375" x="24.4736328125" xml:space="preserve" y="3.0">&lt;&lt;interface&gt;&gt;
Employee</y:NodeLabel>
          <y:UML clipContent="true" constraint="" hasDetailsColor="false" omitDetails="false" stereotype="" use3DEffect="true">
            <y:AttributeLabel xml:space="preserve">+name:string
+age:int</y:AttributeLabel>
            <y:MethodLabel xml:space="preserve">getName(value:string):String
getTitle():String
getStaffNo():Int
getRoom():String
getPhone()</y:MethodLabel>
          </y:UML>
        </y:UMLClassNode>
      </data>
    </node>
  </graph>
  <data key="d6">
    <y:Resources/>
  </data>
</graphml>
```

my Code for the Unit Test looks like this:

```
      public T checkInterfaceOrClass<T> (XmlReader reader, string filepath) where T : BaseModel
        {
            //reader.Settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (getName(reader).Contains("interface"))
                        {
                            InterfaceModel interfaceModel = new InterfaceModel(getName(reader));
                            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(interfaceModel, typeof(InterfaceModel));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ClassObject classModel = new ClassObject(getName(reader));
                            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(classModel, typeof(ClassObject));
                        }
                    }
                }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Wrap it into `CDATA`, if you have ability to change the way it's written

Comment: `<` character is special. You should encode it or else it will corrupt your XML. So that makes your example XML invalid.

Comment: Another option is to read as text rather than xml and parse manually

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski what do you mean with parse manually? I thought my solution was manually, as I am going to take the value and store it into a variable instead of using a parse method of the XmlReader.

Comment: @brstkr you can try use `ReadElementContentAsString` method to get `Name` as simple string and get interface parsing this string, since that can't be recognized as correct xml tag

Comment: @brstkr please, share the entire xml file sample, I'll will add an answer

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thank you so much for the answers, I have tried what u said but was not successful :/ , actually, I have got a .graphml File it is a different representation of xml (with graphical information). I will edit my question and gonna add the .graphml file. The .graphml file can be threatened like a .xml file

Comment: I'm not seeing error.  You can check for error in xml file using Visual Studio.  From VS menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste the xml file into the view.  Errors will show up in the Error List like and compiler error.

Comment: @jdweng I am running an Unit Test and always getting the XML.Exception in the Test-Explorer.

Comment: It looks like the xml was encoded so it could be sent embedded in a html file. (&lt;&lt;).  To decode use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) which give a string result.

Comment: @brstkr Please, check my answer, there is no problem with reading the file. I guess, that `ReadSubtree` method in your code causes an exception

Comment: I think you are reading past the EOF.  Try following :             reader.MoveToContent();
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                //enter code here
                reader.Read();
            }

Comment: @jdweng tried it with while(!reader.EOF) but the XmlReader still crashes.

Comment: I have updated my post and added my unit test code, maybe the issue is there but I can't imagine that ^^

Comment: You are not testing for EOF before reading!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments, I've written a simple snippet (using `ReadToDescendant` method to skip the entire structure of file), with `ReadElementContentAsString` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementcontentasstring?view=netframework-4.8), which works fine

```cs
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("...");
bool canRead = xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("y:NodeLabel");
if (canRead)
{
    var content = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
```

The element content is (there is a `\n` inside string)

```cs
<<interface>>
Employee
```

You can easily parse this string and get a class name with or without `<<interface>>`.

You'll get the same result when use just `Read` method, like here

```cs
bool canRead = xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("y:NodeLabel");
if (canRead)
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        var content = xmlReader.Value;
    }
}
```

Update according you edit with unit test. You don't need to use `MoveToContent`, because `ReadElementContentAsString` already reads the content under current element. But the main problem is that you are calling this method multiple times, because

> This method reads the start tag, the contents of the element, and
> moves the reader past the end element tag.

So, the second call most probably fails. You have to read the content only once and then parse it, instead of reading multiple times

Comment: That's so tricky, I still get the System.Xml.XmlException in my Unit Test with the same message as I posted above. (Nachricht: Ein Name darf nicht mit dem Zeichen '<' beginnen). But thank you for your answer!

Comment: Which line causes an exception?

Comment: I have updated my post and added the code of my unit test maybe this causes the exception.

Comment: You don't need to call `ReadElementContentAsString` multiple times